# GitLab 7.4.2 webhooks does not trigger job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I need help with trigger action on push events from gitlab to jenkins:

I follow all the instructions in https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example, with no success. When I make a commit to my repo nothing happens. The webhook I created seems to be fine, a test it and response OK, but not fire jenkins job.

I'm using GitLab 7.4.2 and Jenkins 2.73.1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how the webhook listener is declared in Jenkins:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teeks99/gitlab-plugin-wiki-images/master/Setup_Example_img/Job_Trigger.png]

If the webhook does fire, but nothing happens, that means the listener does not work (double-check the Jenkins logs to make sure there is no event relative to said webhook)

Change your webhook URL to one generated by [webhook.site](https://webhook.site) (or [requestb.in](https://requestb.in/), or write your own [using ngrok](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/06/07/tools-for-testing-webhooks/), in order to validate that you are able to receive the webhook.

Note: GitLab 7.4.2 seems ancient, so it is possible that [some bugs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=webhook+jenkins) might have been fixed since then (GitLab 10.0.2).
For instance, issues [34143](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34143) and [22515](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22515).